# SQL Server Database Project Add Column to a Table through post deployment script

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, vb.net

In one of our projects, we used SQL Server database project to maintain the database. In here I had a scenario to add new column to database table by script not directly to the table in the project. So I created an alter script to add new column and included it to post deployment script (check column exist before add). It worked with first publish without an error. Here after I publish the project it gives me below error. I understood the problem here it is because of table in the project doesn't contain the column ( because it was added through alter script) So when it is published, it figures it out that the column needs to be dropped.

So can't we achieve add new column not directly to table but through script files in Sql server database project?

```
ERROR: *** Could not deploy package.
2014-07-09 11:15:33 INFO   [Deploy Script]   ERROR: Warning SQL72015: The column [dbo].[aps_client_po].[aps_cost_centre] is being dropped, data loss could occur.
2014-07-09 11:15:33 INFO   [Deploy Script]   ERROR: Warning SQL72015: The column [dbo].[RefPOStaging].[cost_centre] is being dropped, data loss could occur.
2014-07-09 11:15:33 INFO   [Deploy Script]   ERROR: Error SQL72014: .Net SqlClient Data Provider: Msg 50000, Level 16, State 127, Line 6 Rows were detected. The schema update is terminating because data loss might occur.
2014-07-09 11:15:33 INFO   [Deploy Script]   ERROR: Error SQL72045: Script execution error.  The executed script:
2014-07-09 11:15:33 INFO   [Deploy Script]   ERROR: IF EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 1
2014-07-09 11:15:33 INFO   [Deploy Script]   ERROR:            FROM   [dbo].[aps_client_po])
2014-07-09 11:15:33 INFO   [Deploy Script]   ERROR:     RAISERROR (N'Rows were detected. The schema update is terminating because data loss might occur.', 16, 127)
2014-07-09 11:15:33 INFO   [Deploy Script]   ERROR:         WITH NOWAIT;
```

Comment: Can u give u r alter script..

Comment: My question would be why can't you add it to the table script directly (instead of trying to do it through a post-deployment script)?